# canvas html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html

i have a JavaScript project (using jquery), inside it i draw a canvas by code and then i insert array of images on it. it represents fine without any error.

**problem:** `later on, i try to get these images inside from canvas to compare if they have the same src or the same id to don't replace it with the new image`

my functions are:

```
var inter;
var screen;

function onClick(id){
    getScreen(id, function(data){
        screen=window.open('',id,'width=' + data.maxX + ',height=' + data.maxY , true);
        if (screen.document.getElementById("screen") != null ){    
            screen.document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "";
        }
        screen.document.write('<div id="screen"><canvas id="screenCanvas" width=' +
                              data.maxX + ' height=' + data.maxY + 
                              ' style="border:2px solid #000000;color:#000000;" ></canvas></div>');
        draw(data);
        inter = setInterval(function(){screen(id); }, 5000);
    });
}

function screen(id){
    getScreen(id, function(data){
        if (screen.closed == true){
            clearInterval(inter);
            return;
        }
        if((screen.document.getElementById('screenCanvas').width != data.maxX) ||
            (data.maxY != screen.document.getElementById('screenCanvas').height)){
            screen.close();
            screen=window.open('',id,'width=' + data.maxX + ',height=' + data.maxY , true);        
        screen=window.open('',id,'width=' + data.maxX + ',height=' + data.maxY , true);
        if (screen.document.getElementById("screen") != null ){    
            screen.document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "";
        }
        screen.document.write('<div id="screen"><canvas id="screenCanvas" width=' +
                              data.maxX + ' height=' + data.maxY + 
                              ' style="border:2px solid #000000;color:#000000;" ></canvas></div>');
        draw(data);
    });
}

function draw(data) {  
    var canvas = screen.document.getElementById('screenCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    var tileY = 0;
    var tileX = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var tileWidth = data.tileWidth;
    var tileHeight = data.tileHeight;
    for (var i=0;i<(data.maxX/data.tileWidth);i++){  
        for (var j=0;j<(data.maxY/data.tileHeight);j++){  
            var img = new Image();  
            img.onload = (function(img, tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight){
                return function() {
                    context.drawImage(img,tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight);
                }
            })(img, tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight);  
            img.src = "http://myserver:8080/images/screen/tile/" + 
                       data.tiles[counter].imageId; 
            tileX = tileX + parseInt(data.tileWidth); 
            counter ++; 
         } 
        tileY = tileY + parseInt(data.tileHeight); 
        tileX = 0;
    }  
}

</script>
```

this code gets an array `(data) that contains list of (id, maxX, maxY, tileWidth, tileHeight, tiles[x, y, imageId])` and open new window, then write in this window the canvas code and draw images  then calls a timer to work each 5 seconds. after each 5 seconds, screen method calls to re-get the data again and check if screen open then it remove all inner html to rewrite new canvas, and it tests if sizes changes.

this code works fine without any error, but i need to edit these code to get images inside canvas and test it they has the same imageId, don't download it again.(i don't save image id, to get images by, we can store it in img.id, or get images by src since, imageId is a part of image path that makes it unique).

**Note:**

```
id[unique](is the id of the user), 
maxX(maximum width of the screen), 
maxY(maximum height of the screen), 
tileWidth(width of each image), 
tileHeight(height of each image),
tiles(list of images)
    x(left position of the image)
    y(top postion of the image) 
    imageId[unique](id of each image)
example: data[id:1,maxX:1920,maxY:1080,tileWidth:480,tileHeight:270,tiles:(x:2,y:1,imageId:1a)]
```

any help?

Comment: As far as i know you can't get the image drawn to canvas object.What you can do is create an array which contains id of image and compare it with id of  newly downloaded images.

Comment: if i have 16 images, and i compare id's as you mention, i find that 10 id's are different, how can i replace those 10 images only by it's reference in canvas

Comment: is there another way to represent images in html instead of canvas?

Comment: Of course there is, the `img` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `Ravi Jain` said  you can't get the image drawn to canvas object, and as `robertc` said you can use img element.

try these functions that specify the usage of img element not canvas:

```
function onClick(id){
    getScreen(id, function(data){
        var inter;
        var screen;
        var width = parseInt(data.maxX) + parseInt(data.tileWidth);
        var height = parseInt(data.maxY) + parseInt(data.tileHeight);
        screen=window.open('',id,'width=' + width + ',height=' + height , true);
        draw(screen, data);
        inter = setInterval(function(){screen(screen, inter, id); }, 5000);
    });
}

function screen(screen, inter, id){
    getScreen(id, function(data){
        if (screen.closed == true){
            clearInterval(inter);
            return;
        }
        if((screen.document.getElementById("screen").style.width != data.maxX + "px") ||
           (screen.document.getElementById("screen").style.height != data.maxY + "px")){
            screen.close();
            var width = parseInt(data.maxX) + parseInt(data.tileWidth);
            var height = parseInt(data.maxY) + parseInt(data.tileHeight);
            screen=window.open('',id,'width=' + width + ',height=' + height , true);
        }
        draw(screen, data);
    });
}

function draw(screen, data) {
    var screenDiv = screen.document.getElementById("screen");
    if (screenDiv == null) screen.document.write('<div id="screen" style="width:' +
                data.maxX + '; height:' + data.maxY + '; " style="margin: 0 auto;" >');
    var tileY = 0; 
    var tileX = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<(data.maxX/data.tileWidth);i++){ 
        for (var j=0;j<(data.maxY/data.tileHeight);j++){  
            var imageSource = screen.document.getElementById("id_" + counter);
            var path = "http://myserver:8080/images/screen/tile/" + 
                       data.tiles[counter].imageId; 
            if (imageSource == null){
                screen.document.write('<img id="id_' + counter + '" src="' + path +
                '" height="' + data.tileHeight + '" width="' + data.tileWidth + '" />');
            }else if(imageSource.src != path){
                imageSource.src = path;
            }
            tileX = tileX + parseInt(data.tileWidth); 
            counter ++; 
        }
        tileY = tileY + parseInt(data.tileHeight); 
        tileX = 0;
    }
    if (screenDiv == null) screen.document.write('</div>');
}

</script>
```

your code are working fine that's true, but for one instance only, you declare var screen and var inter at the top of the script not in the function, this means that if you click on the first user to get it's screen (as what i understood of your code, what your project did), the timer of the first user stops and of the second user starts. this code that i wrote solve this problem and your problem to replace the source of the image if it changes.

hope this help you man,

GOOD LUCK;

Comment: thanks danny thats true, i have this problem also, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Once you've drawn something on `canvas` it's pixels.  It doesn't retain the object that was used to create those pixels.  If you want this sort of information then you either need to maintain it yourself outside of `canvas`, or use something which retains objects for you [like SVG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-map-element.html#svg-0).