# Separate Javascript code from HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to learn HTML5 Canvas, which drawn from javascript codes.

It seems that I could not separate Javascript code from the original html.
had been looking some solutions:

- [HTML5 Canvas not working in external JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349613/html5-canvas-not-working-in-external-javascript-file)
- [canvas html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032138/canvas-html-tag)

These has not been a solution for me, as after I implement both solutions what appears to me is blank canvas.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Christoper Hans' Paint HTML5 Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="paint.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("paint").getContext("2d");
            ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
            ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            function drawRect(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, fill) {

            ctx.fillStyle=fill;
            ctx.fillRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }

            drawRect(ctx, 100, 100, 200, 250, "FF0000");
        }, false);
// --></script>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="paint" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
</body>
```

I don't know why but only this kind of code *which I got from a post from this website* works and I could not separate the javascript to external file.

TL;DR : Wanted to separate javascript from html to work with canvas.

Any help guys?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Could you rephrase?

Comment: Would you mind posting any error codes you're getting in your browser console?

Comment: putting block HTML comments around `<script>` tags hasn't been required since Netscape 3...

Comment: @akonsu added some brief description on the TL;DR.

Comment: Joe does not seem to get any error on the browser console.
@Alnitak I could not work any other solutions. Please give me alternative than this ancient code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have to guess that you're also copying the `<!--` and `// -->` to your external file. If so, don't do that. You shouldn't even use those anymore, unless you're catering to browsers from last milennium.

Comment: Tried that just now. Did not seem to work too.
Could you please give me an alternative to this solution? The only reason I used this code is because it is the only one that works on my computer.

Comment: I did not see anything.. Tried opening inspect element on chrome. Or am I opening wrong things?

Comment: When you open the inspector, do you see a little red X with a number at the bottom-right corner of the inspector window?

Comment: Could not find that. However, it seems that the javascript does not load at all when I see Network tab of the inspector. Is there something wrong with my javascript linking ? The code was 
    <script src="paint.js" type="text/javasript"></script>
Had also make sure the javascript is named paint.js too.

Comment: `type="text/javasript"` – _really_, or just typo when posting here?

Comment: That seems to be my error. My bad. And all js works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. It is my typo that made any external javascript to not loading.
@CBroe pointed it out and it all seems to be working now.